# Does Yammer API returns RichText

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, yammer

I'm building a windows store app with Xaml to show yammer feeds, and want to show all the text formatting. Since I present a list view, Would it be possible to add a rich text box in the list view and bind the rich labelled text sent by yammer.

For web view control, when I bind it as part of  list view I see that I could not give html text directly via binding property to source.

I see in the return json object of Yammer a field called "rich". Is it the rich text format of the content? If so could I bind it directly to rich text box in windows store app present in the list view?

could some one please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Since I haven't done windows store app programming, this may not answer your question, but the `message.body.rich` object does contain the formatted html (with various tags etc.), which can be rendered directly by any browser.

Comment: so you mean to say the message.body.rich is html text but not rtf text.